# passing a variable to a link in setText in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am very new to ExtJS and JS...

I have an xtype: lable in a form. After something is loaded, this label is updated to present a link.

I previously used:

```
Ext.getCmp('MyForm.MyLabel').setText("<a href='some_permanent_url' target='_blank>'</a>", false);
```

I now want to use a variable in my url but I don't know how to do it.

Something like so would be great:

```
var myVar = some_string;
Ext.getCmp('MyForm.MyLabel').setText("<a href=myVar target='_blank>'</a>", false);
```

This of course, does not work...

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings with `+` operator:

```
var myVar = some_string;
Ext.getCmp('MyForm.MyLabel').setText("<a href='"+myVar+"' target='_blank>'</a>", false);
```